# Extract dictionary pairs into the interactive workspace using ConfigObj or PyYaml

Tags: python, json, parsing, configparser, pyyaml

I have been wanting to define variables in Python by reading them from a simple text file. Therefore I have done some reading on ConfigParser, ConfigObj, PyYaml and JSON. At the moment I am particularly interested in ConfigObj and PyYaml. However I have not managed yet to do what I would like to do in a clean manner.

With ConfigObj and PyYaml I can load everything defined in an external text file into a dictionary. I would like to proceed with this dictionary by extracting all key-value pairs and storing them as separate variables into my interactive workspace.

This is the PyYaml way I have been using thus far:

```
import yaml

config_file = open('myFile', 'r')
config = yaml.read(config_file)

keys = config.keys()
values = config.values()

for i in range(len(keys)):
    string = keys[i] + '=' + str(values[i])
    eval(string)
```

Using `eval` is sometimes frowned about due to possibly allowing all sorts of malicious things to happen. Therefore I would like to know whether PyYaml and/or ConfigObj have an in-built function to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want, assuming I understand your question correctly.

Note: I check for the existence of the key before overwriting it and instead put it under a slightly different name otherwise.

```
import yaml

config_file = open('myFile', 'r')
config = yaml.read(config_file)

keys = config.keys()
values = config.values()

for key,val in zip(keys,values):
    if key not in locals():
        locals()[key] = val
    else:
        locals()[key+"_yaml"] = val
```

While this works, I would actually suggest you just stick to having a dictionary with your values in them. What's wrong with just referencing a dictionary if a local variable doesn't exist?

Comment: Well actually I am working with MATLAB, but I am also using Python for some more flexibility. The eventual goal is to store the parameters defined in the configuration file in a MATLAB binary format (or mat-file). And the MATLAB program that I wrote uses normal local variables, so I had to step away from a dictionary.

Comment: I don't quite understand why that means you need to use locals() in Python, but as long as you understand it's not 'best practice' and the risks and whatnot, etc, and hitherto.

Comment: How else do you propose to store variables in a mat-file? Of course I could rewrite my entire MATLAB program to work differently. But I believe a script needed to parse configurations should conform to a program and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
import __main__
```

then you can

```
__main__.__dict__[keys[i]] = values[i]
```

or even

```
__main__.__dict__.update(config)
```

Whether that is wise or not depends a lot on how much you value being surprised when your global functions are overwritten by yaml entries.